# Combine apoc.convert.fromJsonMap with the CREATE query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi!

I am currently trying to insert a JSON data into `neo4j` with the `apoc.convert.fromJsonMap`. I want to combine the results of this command with the `CREATE` one.

First part worked and gave me a result:

```
WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap('{ "name": "Emil", "from": "Sweden", "klout": 99 }') AS pers
```

But when I want to combine it by creating a new node like this :

```
CREATE (ee:Person pers)
```

I have the following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'p': expected
>   whitespace, comment, NodeLabel, MapLiteral, a parameter, ')' or a
>   relationship pattern (line 2, column 19 (offset: 109)) "CREATE
>   (ee:Person pers)"

I do not know how to pass results of into the `CREATE` query. Any help will be very appreciated :-)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this :

```
WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap('{ "name": "Emil", "from": "Sweden", "klout": 99 }') AS pers
CREATE (ee:Person)
SET ee = pers
RETURN ee
```